# Deploy application in AWS using helm chart in jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, deployment, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I need to deploy an application to AWS  by creating helm chart using jenkins pipeline.

I wrote the following stages :

```
 clone source code

 build the image

 publish docker image in dockerhub

 create the helm chart
```

Now I need to deploy it in AWS. How can I use helm in Jenkins pipeline, and how to deploy the image to AWS?

I am currently a beginner in kubernetes and helm. So I don't understand how to deploy it

Comment: Please provide information on to which AWS services you are trying to deploy.  You can take a look at this plugin for kubernetes deployment https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cli/. Install aws cli and helm in your Jenkins server which will allow you to execute helm and aws command from Jenkins script

Comment: See one way of doing it via my complete tutorial here - https://worklifenotes.com/2021/05/22/helm-cd-with-reliza-hub-tutorial/ - just replace GitHub Actions with Jenkins in your case.

Comment: @Rohit , i am trying to deploy the service in amazon EKS . i need to use AWS role which is already setup in jenkins